# What's Incomplete atrioventricular heart block (AV)?

Tags: physiology, cardiology, heart-failure

This is unclear for me and I can not understand differences between complete and incomplete atrioventricular heart block.also I want an electrocardiograph of incomplete atrioventricular heart block.

Comment: Welcome to Biology S.E.! If you need additional assistance, please visit [The Help Center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help). This question is not necessarily off-topic unless you are asking a personal health question. If this question is a health question; there are plenty of excellent health forums online that are staffed by trained doctors who will be happy to help you.

Comment: @Mad Scientist I didn't know about it at all, when i read about it.I edited my answer as it is acceptable.